# HTML 5 offline cache in Android Chrome

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, manifest, offline

I have a web application that works perfectly well on Desktop Chrome browser, on IPhone and IPad browsers and android build in browser.

However when I tried to run it on the new Chrome for Android it does not works. I found out that the manifest file is not even queried (downloaded). The request for the file is never fired. At least it never arrives to the web server.

Does anybody know, is this feature (offline cache) supported for Chrome on Android? Or is there some other possibility why it would not work?

EDIT: First three lines from main index HTML which is the only HTML in the app.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="resources/advanced/common/cache/application.appcache">
<head>
```

EDIT2:

The weirdest thing, it just started working. Today I sat down and tried to further test the issue. Out of the blue with no changes at all my web server started receiving requests for the manifest file. And all of a sudden the app just works. Now talk about strange.

Answer (score 1):

According to here Chrome for Android does support the App Cache: http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chromemobile.html

Are you sure the HTML syntax is correct and that you have the right MIME type set up for the manifest file on your server?  Reporting any errors that occur might help indicate the problem.

Comment: Yes I am sure. It works on other browsers. I have updated the question with first three lines from HTML. Also the request for manifest never gets to the server. Web server is written in Delphi by myself so I am sure that the request for the manifest just never gets there.

Comment: By the way nice test there. I am ashamed I did not though of that myself :)